# Non-curses pager in C

Tags: c, file, console, pagination

I have written a pager in C that is supposed to be used in systems where `curses` is not installed (or broken). It can also be used as a system-wide pager, it works with `man` pages (only on BSD, though). I want to spot any portability or output problems, as there may be some due to the dependence on buffered input:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
 * A very SIMPLE pager that does not require curses. If your curses library
 * is broken, this is practically the only portable one you can easily get.
 * Written by Daniel Roskams, in the public domain
 */

int
main(
    int argc,
    char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    int ch;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fp = stdin;
    } else if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
        perror(argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (ch == '\n') {
            getchar();
        } else {
            putchar(ch);
        }
    }

    if (ferror(fp)) {
        perror(argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I don't think there are any code problems themselves, since it compiles with the `-Weverything` flag with `clang`.

Comment: I'm not sure I would call displaying one line at a time a "pager", unless you have a two-line display.

Comment: [Follow-up question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/113229/9357)

Answer (score 12):

## Bug

You're code has a bug-ish. When using this, if instead of hitting enter when asked to enter a character you enter some other letter *and then* you press enter, then next newline will be skipped and you will have two lines merged into one:

> ```
> Fooa
> BarHello, World!
> Spama
> Eggs
> ```

where the text file was:

> ```
> Foo
> Bar
> Hello, World!
> Spam
> Eggs
> ```

To be honest, I'm not quite sure which line this is occurring on, but I think it has something to do with the `getchar()` call; when I pressed `a`, the next line was printed out.

## Bug #2

Using the same file as above but this time passing it through STDIN like so:

```
./a.out < Foo
```

I got this as a result:

> ```
>  Fooarello, World!pamggs
> ```

I didn't touch the keyboard at all; it just flew through the file. I don't think this is intended.

However, this time, I think I know why. It's this line:

```
getchar();
```

When the end of a line is reached, then this is called. However, since the file you are reading is from `stdin` **and** `getchar()` *also* reads from `stdin`, then this call is going to remove the next character from the file.

See the input again, but with the characters removed by `getchar`:

> Foo**b**ar**H**ello, World!**s**pam**e**ggs

The bolded characters are the characters that appeared after each newline.

Comment: @AnonymousShadow You have posted a follow-up question, so I assume that you found this answer to be helpful. I suggest that you mark it as an accepted answer.