# Non-curses pager in C (revision 2)

Tags: c, file, console, portability

In this revision (follow-up of [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/113225/23788)) I've fixed reading from stdin, and also tried to minimise the damage caused by typing additional characters. You might want to see my original post on this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
 * A very SIMPLE pager that does not require curses. If your curses library
 * is broken, this is practically the only portable one you can easily get.
 */

int
main(
    int argc,
    char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    FILE *tty;
    int ch;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fp = stdin;
    } else if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
        perror(argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if ((tty = fopen("/dev/tty", "r")) == NULL) {
        perror("/dev/tty");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (ch == '\n') {
            while (fgetc(tty) != '\n');
        } else {
            putchar(ch);
        }
    }

    if (ferror(fp)) {
        perror(argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Some questions:

- How can I avoid having to read from /dev/tty? I know that the device file is available on practically all Unixes, but it won't work on Windows.
- Also, I want to avoid dependency on any library except standard C.

Comment: why aren't you reading from stdin in all cases?

Answer (score 2):

## Making the code portable again

You did a fine job cleaning up last code's bugs. My answer will be fairly short this time.

> How can I avoid having to read from /dev/tty? I know that the device
> file is available on practically all Unixes, but it won't work on
> Windows.

Well, I have some good news and some bad news.

**Bad News**

The bad news is that I'm pretty sure the only way you aren't going to get that bug where you substitute the file for `STDIN` is if you continue reading from `/dev/tty`. After all, you can't possibly read from STDIN because that's where the file is.

---

You can stop now. As a quick and smart fix, you can drop support for reading from STDIN (I mean, who would use a pager to read something they are typing into STDIN?). Or, if you want you can read on for the good news.

---

**Good News**

There's a solution that allows you to keep on reading from `/dev/tty` and that is to use the amazing Windows API. Luckily, you can do that in C because Windows provides a header file `windows.h` that gives you full access to the Windows API in your C/C++ code.

Now, you may think to just include the `windows.h` file in your code and use whatever the API has to read the keyboard. Well, you can't quite do that because if you try compiling that on *nix, you'll get an error saying that the `windows.h` could not be found.

An easy fix is to use the pre-processor:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#endif
```

This will make sure to only include the `windows.h` file if the operating system is a Windows one.

Then, in the section where you would normally open and read from the `/dev/tty` file, you would encase that in:

```
#ifdef linux
...
#endif
```

and the Windows code in the respective pre-processor statements.

As for what actually goes inside the Windows code sections, I am unsure. Through some quick searching, I came across [`ReadConsole`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684958(v=vs.85).aspx) in the API index. However, I have not tested it out. If that does not work, feel free to explore the API for other possibilities.

Comment: @AnonymousShadow No, that is correct. However, you could just as easily pass the file in as an argument.